# Displaying a register's value in LC-3

Tags: lc3

I was wondering how to display/output the value in a register.

ex: R3 has the value of 2 stored into it.  I want to display that number to the screen.

This code below doesn't work because it tells me i need a label. I've also tried storing the value of R3 into R0, but when i display it i get some funky symbol(s)

LEA R0, R3
PUTS

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OUT` instruction, and make sure you output ASCII codes:

```
AND R0, R0, #0
LD  R0, ZERO
ADD R0, R0, R3
OUT
HALT

ZERO: .fill x30  ; ASCII code for '0'
```

Note: this will only work for single digit numbers (0-9). If you want to display a number with more than 1 digit, you have to loop through all of it's digits.